# How can I set notebook's options without opening it?

Tags: notebooks

At present moment, to batch apply a change in a set of notebook I use a "brute force", rough, method:

```
(* simple example *)
setBackgroundBlue[notebookFileName_] := Module[
   {tempNb},
   tempNb = NotebookOpen[notebookFileName];
   SetOptions[tempNb, Background -> Blue];
   NotebookSave[tempNb];
   NotebookClose[tempNb];
   ];
SetAttributes[setBackgroundBlue, Listable];
```

but I bet that there exists a smarter one. Please, can you provide any hint ?
I have been brooding about text processing notebooks file, but it's prone to error, especially when dealing with complex structure in TaggingRules..

Comment: I'm doing what you are doing. I was thinking about that for a long time and I'm afraid I don't have good news about alternative ways. Another approach could be to use `NotebookGet`, then it will be easier to deal with a Notebook expression than with pure text. Isn't really different from what you method does and is less handy. Additionaly, you may want to use this method to avoid prompting dynamics [Create a notebook and save it without prompting Dynamics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113290/5478).

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! The reason why I'm trying to do that is a long tale and I'm going to post a specific question. By the way, for now, are you aware of any snippet manager particularly fitting Mathematica's code ?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question, could you clarify?

Comment: @Kuba There is a plenty of "free snippet manager" in Internet, and I will post a specific question about snippet manager for Mathematica's code, including an hypothetical  "wish list". For the present moment I'm simply curious to learn from a seasoned programmer if he have any predilection among them.