# Toggling DynamicUpdating aborts dynamics with UpdateInterval

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, options

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier, fixed in 11.1.0**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3710168] was created.
>
> [...] I was able to reproduce the issue [...] I am checking with the development team to see if we have a workaround for this.

---

After switching `DynamicUpdating` off and on, the `Dynamic` with `UpdateInterval` option displays `$Aborted`.

```
Dynamic[RandomReal[], UpdateInterval -> 1]

x = 1; Dynamic[x]
Slider @ Dynamic[x]

Checkbox @ Dynamic @ CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DynamicUpdating]
```

[image]

Worth to mention that if this notebook is saved in an untrusted path, opened and is asking to `"Enable Dynamic Updating"` then it works fine.

Also, toggling with Evaluation/DynamicUpdatingEnabled menu item works fine.

It makes the answer to [Create a notebook and save it without prompting Dynamics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109651/5478) partially unusable.

Comment: this seems to be fixed in 11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround that will be enough in many of cases.

The downside is that you will not have any precise indication, like in original `Checkbox`, whether it is enabled or not. It is because `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DynamicUpdating]` stays `Automatic`.

To the point, you can toggle it with a token:

```
Button["ToggleDynamicUpdating", 
 FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "ToggleDynamicUpdating"]
]
```

- [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5478)