# Controllers going out of sync after re-enabling dynamic updating (if external changes were made)

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, options

**Bug reproduced in V10.4.1 and persisting through V11.0.1**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3713364] was created
>
> [...] I was able to reproduce the issue, and consequently, I filed a report with our development team raising the issues [...]

---

Probably closely related to [Toggling DynamicUpdating aborts dynamics with UpdateInterval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125932/5478) yet different enough to deserve a separate question.

Please follow those steps to reproduce the problem:

- evaluate `(CreateDocument[#]; #) & @ Slider @ Dynamic @ x`
- confirm that both sliders are in synch
- disable dynamics in one of the notebooks, e.g. via Evaluation menu
- move the slider in the second notebook
- (**!**) move mouse over the disabled one again (it glitches to `0` value but is still disabled)
- enable dynamic updating
- (**!**) try to move that slider, changes are reflected in the second one but the appearance/state of this one is not updated

[image]